# Camera shaped Vision problem in 3D view

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I have clicked wrong keys and now im not able to turn it off and now i only see what was in the camera shaped box.

[image]

Comment: Probably you hit alt+b it's a hide mask tool.

Comment: To turn it off just hit alt+B again